# minimal (strongly) KC

Tags: gn.general-topology

If P is a topological property, then  a space (X, τ)  is said to be minimal P (respectively, maximal) if (X,τ) has property P but no topology on X which is strictly smaller (respectively, strictly larger ) than τ has P.

- A topological space is  called KC space  if every compact subset is closed.
- A topological space is  called strongly KC space  if every  countably compact subset is closed.

I know (strongly) KC – space is topological property.

I want to know:

1. Is there a example of a minimal KC but not minimal strongly KC – space?
2. It is a fact that an infinite minimal strongly KC space has a trivial convergent sequence, but it does not hold for minimal KC space. I want an easy example to show it.

Comment: Dear fatemeh: I answered your previous question about KC spaces, and apparently you didn´t even read it or didn´t bother to either accept it or comment on the answer.

Comment: A small suggestion: I think the several .......... appearing in the question are unnecessary. Perhaps you just want to start a new paragraph?